# how to change the size of a text added on an image with linux comand "convert -draw"

Tags: linux, imagemagick-convert

I use the linux command "convert -draw 'text 500,100 Toto'" to add the text 'Toto' on an image at the position x=500 y=100.
How can I change the size of this text ?
thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-pointsize N` where N is a number and represent the size.

More options for font?

```
$ convert|grep font
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
  -display server      get image or font from this X server
  -family name         render text with this font family
  -font name           render text with this font
  -pointsize value     font point size
  -stretch type        render text with this font stretch
  -style type          render text with this font style
  -weight type         render text with this font weight
```

...and finally use `-fill colorname` before each `-draw` (several possible) for font color.